Theorems display error with hyperref
I have a problem with display theorem counter (see below) and I cant just update everything because of corporate policies, so I am trying to find exact simple solution.
I've already found that problem arises because of \usepackage{hyperref}. In every other aspect hyperref works fine (not included in MWE) but for some reason it produces the following error in interaction with amsthm.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\usepackage[hypertexnames = false]{hyperref}

\title{Title page}
\author{JFK}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Some section}
Check

\begin{test}
First test.
\end{test}

\begin{test}
Second test.
\end{test}

\section{Other section}

\begin{test}
One more test.
\end{test}

\end{document}






I understand that on comlete fully updated installation there is no such problem. I've checked. But on corporate laptop I have not one. Some packages are outdated, some are new. I can propose to update specific packages to solve my problem, but I cant request full up to date installation. Just FYI.
I am greatfully appriciate any ideas how to fix the problem with minimum efforts.

well at first try your own document. As you are loading sourcesanspro it can not  produce the screenshot you are showing. I do not see the problem, if you really get it with your document show the log-file.

@UlrikeFischer I cant download full log file but added screens with errors parts

look when I ask for a log I want a log. Your screenshots show only parts of the story. But beside this: you have a new hyperref and an old LaTeX format/L3 layer. That won't work. hyperref and LaTeX belong together nowadays and should be updated together. You can try \ExplSyntaxOn\cs_generate_variant:Nn\tl_gset:Nn{Ne}\ExplSyntaxOff  but without any garanty that it doesn't break somewhere else.

@ Thank you so much for short detailed explanation about core of the problem! I updated l3backend, l3kernel, l3packages and now everything works fine!

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)
I am unable to generate any problems with the OP's code on an up-to-date MacTeX2024 system, under pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or XeLaTeX. (I've streamlined the OP's code for the following example.)

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} % optional
\crefname{test}{test}{tests}

\begin{document}

\begin{test} \label{test:a} First test. \end{test}
\begin{test} \label{test:b} Second test. \end{test}
\begin{test} \label{test:c} One more test. \end{test}

Cross-references to tests \ref{test:a} to \ref{test:c}.

Cross-references to \cref{test:a,test:b,test:c}.

\end{document}

